# NSCFString objectForKey unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, ios5

```
//initialize the people data list
- (void)initializePeopleListFromJson:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate auraId:(NSString *)auraId
{

//initialize the NSMutableArray list
self.peopleList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//retrieve the coordinate of myself
//NSString *myCoordinate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
NSString *myCoordinate = @"31.2,121.6";

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", @"http://services.portaura.mobi/AuraMesh/auraFinder/findPeoples?ll=", myCoordinate, @"&source=tencent,netease,kaixin&myAuraId=", auraId];

NSLog(@"*********** %@", url);

//retrieve the people list from web service
NSDictionary* result = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:url];
NSArray *peopleListFromJson = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
```

// NSLog(@"peopleList: %@", peopleListFromJson);

```
People *people;
UserProfile *userProfile;
NSDictionary *geoFromJson;
NSDictionary *profileFromJson;



for (NSDictionary *peopleFromJson in peopleListFromJson)
{

    people = [[People alloc] init];
    userProfile = [[UserProfile alloc] init];

    people.foreignId = [peopleFromJson objectForKey:@"foreignId"];
    people.id1 = [peopleFromJson objectForKey:@"id"];
    people.isFavorited = [peopleFromJson objectForKey:@"isFavorited"];
    people.lastActiveTime = [peopleFromJson objectForKey:@"lastActiveTime"];
    people.lastActivity = [peopleFromJson objectForKey:@"lastActivity"];
    people.lastPlace = [peopleFromJson objectForKey:@"lastPlace"];
    people.source = [peopleFromJson objectForKey:@"source"];

    NSLog(@"AAAAAAAA %@", [peopleFromJson objectForKey:@"foreignId"]);


    //process geo
    geoFromJson = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    geoFromJson = [peopleFromJson objectForKey:@"geo"];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = [[geoFromJson objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
    coordinate.longitude = [[geoFromJson objectForKey:@"lng"] floatValue];

    people.geo = coordinate;
    people.distance = [geoFromJson objectForKey:@"distance"];


    //process profile
    profileFromJson = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    profileFromJson = [peopleFromJson objectForKey:@"profile"];

    people.avatar = [profileFromJson objectForKey:@"avatar"];
    people.gender = [profileFromJson objectForKey:@"gender"];
    people.location = [profileFromJson objectForKey:@"location"];
    people.screenName = [profileFromJson objectForKey:@"screenName"];
    people.signature = [profileFromJson objectForKey:@"sigunature"];

    //people.userProfile = userProfile;
    [self addPeople:people];

}
```

}

```
it  give me the [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1808d0,can you give some advice
```

json like :

{"status":0,"data":{"list":[{"foreignId":"8827857641648129226","geo":{"distance":1359,"lat":31.20926508184017,"lng":121.59068046014856},"id":"netease_8827857641648129226","isFavorited":false,"lastActiveTime":"2012-05-19T20:26:47Z","lastActivity":"Goal http://126.fm/kFEKl","lastPlace":"","profile":{"avatar":"http://oimagea3.ydstatic.com/image?w=48&h=48&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmimg.126.net%2Fp%2Fbutter%2F1008031648%2Fimg%2Fface_big.gif","gender":0,"location":"","screenName":"4671784460","sigunature":"","tags": []},"source":"netease"}......

Comment: Most likely `profileFromJson = [peopleFromJson objectForKey:@"profile"];` returns a NSString instead of a NSDictionary.... how does the JSON really look?

Comment: i am a new iOS developer,i am modifying other people code.thank you

Comment: i think you are not right always,because depend on JSON,sometimes is correct  is NSDictionary. sometimes is NSString.

Comment: That is the thing, sometimes it returns a dictionary and you are lucky because it works but sometimes it doesn't and then you crash. You need to test the return type before using it

Comment: i test if i used @"data.list" ,i cannot check return type before using it ,it also right.so i think this depend on the json your write style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check ur variable class `peopleFromJson` it might not be a dictionary at the moment you are calling objectForKey.

put this statement as first line in ur `for` loop
`NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([peopleFromJson class]));`

Comment: you are right,peopleFromJson not a NSDictionary,can you give other search  key to help me solve the problem .and json link also Ok thank you

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem,i cannot think the problem is easy,maybe some people only know the cause is the object is NSString not NSDir,but the real problem is depend on json "style",sometimes my code is correct,but for other json is not correct for example my question json. so solved is :

```
if ( ![peopleListFromJson isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && peopleListFromJson!=nil) {
    peopleListFromJson =[NSArray arrayWithObject:peopleListFromJson];
}

because i used 
NSDictionary* result = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:url];
NSArray *peopleListFromJson = [result valueForKeyPath:@"data.list"];
so peopleListFromJson!=nil is impotent
```